# I get null response in php using sqlsrv_query method

Tags: php, api, get

```
{
    "error": false,
    "register": {
        "GcmRegId": null,
        "PartyName": null,
        "PersonName": null,
        "MobileNo": null,
        "EmailID": null,
        "strCategory": null,
        "createdAt": null
    },
    "responce_code": 200,
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_msg": "Registration successfull"
}
```

$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.SPL (GcmRegId,PartyName,PersonName,MobileNo,EmailID,strCategory,CreatedAt) VALUES ('$GcmRegId','$PartyName','$PersonName','$MobileNo','$EmailID','$strCategory',getdate())";
    $var = array($GcmRegId,$PartyName,$PersonName,$MobileNo,$EmailID,$strCategory,$createdAt);
    $result = sqlsrv_query($pdo,$query,$var);
        if($result){
            $register = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,(SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC));
            //$response["register"] = $register;
            $response["register"]["GcmRegId"] = $register["GcmRegId"];
            $response["register"]["PartyName"] = $register["PartyName"];
            $response["register"]["PersonName"] = $register["PersonName"];
            $response["register"]["MobileNo"] = $register["MobileNo"]; 
            $response["register"]["EmailID"] = $register["EmailID"];
            $response["register"]["strCategory"] = $register["strCategory"];
            $response["register"]["createdAt"] = $register["createdAt"];
            $response["responce_code"] = 200;
            $response["error_code"] = 0;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Registration successfull";
            //echo json_encode($register);
            echo json_encode($response);

Comment: Can you add the arguments that you call `sqlsrv_query` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Input:]    
<?php
    #$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1234","spl_database");
    $response = array("error" => FALSE);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include 'db_connect.php';
    $db = new db_connect();
    $pdo = $db->connect();

    // echo "hello";
    // echo json_encode($response);

    if (isset($_POST['GcmRegId']) && isset($_POST['PartyName']) && isset($_POST['PersonName']) && isset($_POST['MobileNo']) && isset($_POST['EmailID']) && isset($_POST['strCategory']) && isset($_POST['createdAt']))
    { 

        $GcmRegId = $_POST['GcmRegId'];
        $PartyName = $_POST['PartyName'];
        $PersonName = $_POST['PersonName'];
        $MobileNo = $_POST['MobileNo'];
        $EmailID = $_POST['EmailID'];
        $strCategory = $_POST['strCategory'];
        $createdAt = $_POST['createdAt'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.SPL WHERE MobileNo = $MobileNo";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($pdo,$query);
        $result = sqlsrv_has_rows($result);
        if ($result === true) {
            $response["error_code"] = 0;
            $response["error_msg"] = " Alredy register with" . $MobileNo;
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.SPL (GcmRegId,PartyName,PersonName,MobileNo,EmailID,strCategory,createdAt) VALUES ('$GcmRegId','$PartyName','$PersonName','$MobileNo','$EmailID','$strCategory',getdate())";
            $var = array($GcmRegId,$PartyName,$PersonName,$MobileNo,$EmailID,$strCategory,$createdAt);   
            $result = sqlsrv_query($pdo,$query,$var);
            if ($result) {
                $register = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,(SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC));
                $response["register"] = $register;
                $response["register"]["GcmRegId"] = $register . $GcmRegId;
                $response["register"]["PartyName"] = $register . $PartyName;
                $response["register"]["PersonName"] = $register. $PersonName;
                $response["register"]["MobileNo"] = $register . $MobileNo; 
                $response["register"]["EmailID"] = $register . $EmailID;
                $response["register"]["strCategory"] = $register . $strCategory;
                $response["register"]["createdAt"] = $register . $createdAt;
                $response["responce_code"] = 200;
                $response["error_code"] = 0;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Registration successfull";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }else{
                $response["error_code"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Registration unsuccessfull";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }enter code here
    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Output:]    
{
        "error": false,
        "register": {
            "GcmRegId": "xyz",
            "PartyName": "ENTERPRISE",
            "PersonName": "MEHUL",
            "MobileNo": "7984548439",
            "EmailID": "rips@gmail.com",
            "strCategory": "Party Group",
            "createdAt": "27/11/2019"
        },
        "responce_code": 200,
        "error_code": 0,
        "error_msg": "Registration successfull"
    }
```